# Custom error message for WooCommerce coupons

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to set my own error messages for coupons in WooCommerce. I mean the error messages like "The minimum spend for this coupon is xxx". I could just put my own message in class-wc-coupon.php but I need different message for different coupons.

The perfect way to set this message would be as [a coupon description](https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/barczakinfo/12w238ledd.png). I found out that coupons are stored in wp_posts where post_type=shop_coupon. How can I extract this string and put it [in the place of WooCommerce error message](https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/barczakinfo/deqzb5dsux.png).

Answer (score 0):

I posted an answer to a similar question linked below, however I could only get Coupon Messages working. Figured it might help you (or another user) to customise Coupon Errors... If you do, be sure to let us know! :-)

[How to hide specific messages in woocommerce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39955771/how-to-hide-specific-messages-in-woocommerce/44742512#44742512)